# hosting an image with the flask and then processing the same using another view function in the same code

Tags: python, web-services, flask

so I am hosting an image using flask and then I want to do a post request to an API using the url all in the same code:

```
@app.route('/host')
def host():
    return send_from_directory("C:/images", "image1.png")

@app.route('/post')
def post():
    response = requests.post(url, data={'input':'<url for host>', headers=headers)
    return jsonify(response.json())
```

I believe as both these view functions are in the same python file, post() gets blocked.
Is there a workaround this problem ?

PS: if I host images on a different machine, it works, but that's not what I desire.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some problems with your code.

First, I don't believe there is an `@app.post()` decorator in Flask. My guess is that you were trying to specify that that route should be POSTed to by your users. The way to do that would be `@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])`.

Next, it seems like you want the `/post` endpoint to send a POST request to a user-specified(?) URL when the user sends an HTTP request to this endpoint. The way you would do that for a user-specified / user-POSTed URL is something like this (I haven't run this code to test it):

```
@app.route('/send_post_request', methods=['POST'])
def send_post_request():
    user_posted_data = json.loads(request.data)
    user_specified_url = user_posted_data['url']
    dict_to_post= { 'input': url_for('hosts') }
    headers = {}  # Fill these in
    response = requests.post(user_specified_url , json=dict_to_post, headers=headers)
    return jsonify(response.json())
```

If the URL to send the POST request to is known by the server, you could have your user simply send a GET request:

```
@app.route('/send_post_request', methods=['GET'])
def send_post_request():
    dict_to_post = { 'input': url_for('hosts') }
    headers = {}  # Fill these in
    server_specified_url = ''  # Fill this in
    response = requests.post(server_specified_url, json=dict_to_post, headers=headers)
    return jsonify(response.json())
```

Comment: yes, I meant to write `@app.route('/post')` and what you posted is basically what I was doing and its still blocking. After a while the connection gets aborted.

Comment: Are you sure that your old version of the server isn't still running? Try typing `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` and manually shutting down all of your running Python processes.

Also, if you send a manual POST request to the URL you have specified, are you sure that you get a response? It could be that the Python server is waiting for a response from the other server.

Comment: yup, I tried manually shutting down all the Python processes, still the same. Also, I do get a response with a manual POST request to the url.

Comment: Can you run your code with a debugger (like the one in PyCharm) and see exactly what's happening on the server when a request comes in?

Comment: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))` It keeps sending the request and gives up after a while after not getting a response. First it calls the `host()` view function and then `post()`, but I think it's not functioning properly for the same reasons I mentioned before.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that error. I recommend posting the full contents of your code in your question to help others spot potential problems in your code.

Comment: I used the post request in a different python file without using flask on the same machine as the one hosting the images using the flask, it works. Moreover, I copied the code like the one above on a different machine running on the same network and called the post function using flask, but used urls of images hosted on the previous machine and it still works. I believe, there isn't any problem with the code(I also consulted with a friend to check it). I'll keep you posted if I find a way :)